# Multiple area with different Baseline in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I would like to plot multiple "area" with different baseline value on the same axis in MATLAB 2017a. It seems that the behavior has changed with the graphical update (HG2). Is there a workaround?

Here is my sample code:

```
x = 1: 10;
y1 = rand( 10, 1 );
baseline1 = 2;
hold on
a1 = area( x, y1 + baseline1, baseline1, 'FaceColor', 'r' );
disp( a1.BaseValue );
y2 = rand( 10, 1 );
baseline2 = -1;
a2 = area( x, y2 + baseline2, baseline2, 'FaceColor', 'g' );
disp( a1.BaseValue );
```

The `a1` area baseline updates when creating the second area `a2`. I would like the `a1` properties to remain the same.

EDIT : I added the `disp` command showing that the property have been updated.

Comment: the only thing changes when I run your code after the second call to `area` is the `ylim` of the axes

Comment: Did you use MATLAB 2017a version ? I have checked again with the edited code with disp  and it shows that the property changed after the second call to area

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [documented behavior](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/baseline-properties.html?searchHighlight=Baseline&s_tid=doc_srchtitle#property_d0e69521) (and it happens at least since 2016a):

> Typically, baselines are associated with bar series, stem series, or area objects. The BaseValue property for the associated object and the BaseValue property for the baseline object always have the same value. **Setting one property also sets the other property**. The BaseLine property for the associated object contains the baseline object.

So basically `BaseLine` is more like a property of the *axes* that all the `area` objects within it inherent with its values. This is true for all properties of `BaseLine`, not only the `BaseValue`.

My proposed workaround is to use different axes, then link them with `linkaxes`:

```
ax(1) = axes;
a1 = area(ax(1), x, y1 + baseline1, baseline1, 'FaceColor', 'r' );
ax(2) = axes;
a2 = area(ax(2), x, y2 + baseline2, baseline2, 'FaceColor', 'g' );
axis off % turn off the secon axes
limits = cell2mat(get(ax,'YLim')); % get both axes limits
set(ax,'YLim',[min(limits(:)) max(limits(:))]); % set the same values for both axes
linkaxes(ax)
```

The result:

[image: area baseline]

Comment: Ok thank you for the workaround. If the user zooms or somehow changes some visual settings, I have to update the other axes too.

Comment: To make the `axes` update together, add `linkaxes(ax)` after you set them. See my edit.